# Hide CreateForm and EditForm on Admin-on-Rest conditionally

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm using admin-on-rest for budget tracking. If I want my admin panel to switch back to last year then I render data on the grid accordingly.

Our client wants a feature to hide Create Button and Edit button from the admin panel, if the data belongs to last year, else show as it is.

I tried to change my code in App.js something like this.
This code worked and I just tried with createform. But the moment I try to save the form the routing to list doesn't take place. You can see the JSX code in the link below.

[App.js Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS4cG.png)

If there's any other optimum solution. Please guide me.

Comment: do not post your code as an image.

Answer (score 0):

**Very Important**: Please always share your code and do not share images. Very hard to copy paste and correct.

1) You cannot really use Admin like that. To control display of edit button you need to control it in the datagrid.

```
export const SomeList = (props) => {
  return (
    <List {...props}
          >
      <Datagrid>
        <TextField source="id" label="Id" />
        {props.record.date >= thisYearBeginning ?
          (<EditButton />) : null 
        }
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  )
}
```

Controlling Create would be trickier. 1 way to do it would be to recreate the Create Button and pass it to List as a custom action using below docs. Then you can use logic like above ^^ to also control whether customCreate is displayed or not. Ask me questions if you have problems recreating Create.

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/List.html#actions

Comment: I apologise for putting an image of the code. But I was helpless as I was getting persistent error on my code.

I don't have any issue with edit button. I tried the same way to hide it. I have issue with the create button.

Comment: Yeah the create button would be tricker. I have outlined a strategy that I think will work. You can edit your question above and buzz me here and I can try and help. usually AOR components can be recreated by copy pasting the code and relinking the dependencies, then you can make your custom changes.

Comment: Also your custom logic for Admin might just work if you do something like below (
currentPermission === 'something' ? (<Admin edit=edit create=create>) : (<Admin edit=edit>)

) The round braces are the trick in react

Comment: Thanks for your time guys. I have got the solution for this thing.

Basically, I played the ternary operator condition in the create props which did my first part of hiding and showing create button.

The next part, where my application got frozen while redirecting the user to the list after submitting the form.

Comment: If you have a solution then it would be great if you could share your code and make it the selected answer and also please upvote my answer if it helped in any way. Thanks.

Comment: I had a problem on the second part.

When redirecting the create form to list, the API call was made in the App.js to fetch the current selected year and the rendering of the layout was happening. This inhibited the flow of my application. After then I used localStorage to fetch the value of current year and avoid superfluous work. So now I get sleek performance from here onwards.

Comment: <Resource
          name="Category"
          options={{ label: "Category" }}
          list={Category}
          icon={CategoryIcon}
          create={this.state.isCurrentyear ? CategoryCreate : null}
          edit={this.state.isCurrentyear ? CategoryEdit : null}
        />

Comment: I used the ternary operator on my resource tags. That way I can hide the editbutton too from the main page itself

Comment: Hey there. You can also write all your comments into an answer. SO allows you to write answers to your own questions and also lets you accept them as the answer. Will help future visitors who may be facing the same problem.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for this. I got involved in work hence didn't got time to write it as an answer